# Failed to start MySQL Community Server After Updating to Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I have updated my Ubuntu server on DigitalOcean to version 22.04.2. Now I can't log in to the phpMyAdmin ( also my Flask website can't connect to the MYSQL ). When trying to login to the phpMyAdmin gives me these 4 error messages.

- Cannot log in to the MySQL server
- mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused
- Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed
- mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

I have already tried to comment out the

```
query_cache_limit =

query_cache_size =
```

from the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file. But it doesn't work too.

```
systemctl status mysql.service
```

shows the following.

```
× mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-03-07 04:55:10 UTC; 52min ago
    Process: 1830 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 30ms

Mar 07 04:55:09 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 07 04:55:09 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 04:55:09 mail systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

and the `journalctl -xeu mysql.service` shows as

```
An ExecStartPre= process belonging to unit mysql.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 07 04:55:09 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 04:55:09 mail systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1559 and the job result is failed.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A stop job for unit mysql.service has finished.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1642 and the job result is done.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ The unit mysql.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 07 04:55:10 mail systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysql.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
░░ 
░░ A start job for unit mysql.service has finished with a failure.
░░ 
░░ The job identifier is 1642 and the job result is failed.
```

How to fix this and where to start ?.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to troubleshoot this issue, there are a few steps you can take.

Firstly, you can check if MySQL is running by using the command "`sudo systemctl status mysql.service`" in the terminal. If MySQL is not running, you can check the error log at "`/var/log/mysql/error.log`" for any error messages that could help diagnose the problem. Restarting MySQL using "`sudo systemctl restart mysql.service`" is another option.

You can also check the MySQL configuration file at "`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`" for any configuration issues, and make sure that the firewall settings are not blocking traffic to MySQL.

Finally, checking the MySQL user accounts and permissions using "`sudo mysql -u root -p`" in the terminal could help solve the issue. If none of these steps work, seeking further help from a MySQL expert or DigitalOcean support team might be necessary.

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: `sudo systemctl status mysql.service` result is "Failed"
`tail error.log` gives nothing.
`sudo systemctl restart mysql.service` gives this
' unable to resolve host mail: Name or service not known
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.'

Comment: If the "systemctl status mysql.service" command returns "Failed" and the MySQL error log is not helpful, there may be a configuration issue with MySQL. You can try checking for configuration issues, checking if MySQL is running on the correct port, ensuring enough disk space is available, or reinstalling MySQL. If none of these steps work, I am out of ideas.

Comment: `mysql -u root -p` gives 'mysql: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 23.
mysql: [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!'

is it means that the error with my,cnf file ?

Comment: Yes, the error message "Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 23" means that there is an issue with the my.cnf configuration file for MySQL. This error occurs when there is a configuration parameter in the my.cnf file that is not correctly associated with a specific section or group.

To fix this error, you should edit the my.cnf file and ensure that all configuration parameters are correctly grouped under the appropriate section. Additionally, you should check for any syntax errors or typos in the configuration file.

Comment: After fixing the configuration file, you can restart the MySQL service using the "sudo systemctl restart mysql.service" command. Once the service is restarted, you can try running the "mysql -u root -p" command again to see if the issue has been resolved.

Comment: tried `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service` after clearing the my.cnf file (now it have only these values '!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/'). But still the same error. `sudo systemctl restart mysql.service`

sudo: unable to resolve host mail: Name or service not known
Job for mysql.service failed.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" for details.

Comment: The error message "sudo: unable to resolve host mail: Name or service not known" indicates a problem with your server's hostname or DNS resolution. To fix this error, you should update your server's hostname by editing the "/etc/hostname" and "/etc/hosts" files, and then restart the networking service using the "sudo systemctl restart networking.service" command.

Comment: After updating the hostname and hosts files and restarting the networking service, you can try restarting the MySQL service using "sudo systemctl restart mysql.service" again. If the error persists, check the MySQL error log file "/var/log/mysql/error.log" and the output of the "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xeu mysql.service" commands for more details about the error.

Comment: Had to reconfigure the host name. And then removed mysql completely and reinstalled and configured. Now its working. Thank you very much for your time to help my issue.